# Error while making predictions using GBM in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, gbm

I need a quick help. I have been trying to simply apply GBM but I am facing an error which I am not being able to resolve. Please help. The data sets used can be found at 'https://www.kaggle.com/c/boston-housing/data' 
Code:

```
data1 <- read.csv("train.csv") 
data2 <- read.csv("test.csv") 
data2$medv<- NA

GBM library(caret) 
library(gbm) 
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10) 

tune_Grid <- expand.grid(interaction.depth = 2, n.trees = 500, shrinkage = 0.1, n.minobsinnode = 10)
set.seed(825) 
fit <- train(medv ~ ., data = data1, method = "gbm", trControl = fitControl, verbose = FALSE, tuneGrid = tune_Grid)
```

Everything works fine till here. The problem occurs when I predict.

```
predicted <- predict(fit,data2,type= "prob")

> predicted <- predict(fit,data2,type= "prob") Error in [.data.frame(out, , obsLevels, drop = FALSE) : undefined columns selected
```

However, if I remove the type parameter, it works without any error.

```
predicted <- predict(fit,data2)

> predicted <- predict(fit,data2) 
>
```

Please help what am I missing.

Thanks,
Priyank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`medv` from boston housing data is not a vector of classes but rather a continuous outcome.

```
train$medv[1:20]
[1] 24.0 21.6 33.4 36.2 22.9 15.0 18.9 21.7 20.4 18.2 19.9 23.1 20.2 13.6 19.6 15.2 14.5 14.8 12.7 14.5
```

When `type = "probs"` is set the `caret` function `predict.train` outputs a data frame of class probabilities. This would not make sense for a continuous variable hence it returns an error. Usually model performance on a continuous outcome is evaluated using RMSE (root mean squared error) which you can calculate using the `caret` function `postResample`.

postResample:
Given two numeric vectors of data, the mean squared error and R-squared are calculated. For two factors, the overall agreement rate and Kappa are determined.